# Stably free module not finitely generated is free

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, projective-modules

Hi. I have read that stably free modules not finitely generated are free; this is proved in 
M.R. Gabel, *stably free projectives over commutative rings*, Thesis, Brandeis Univ., Waltham, MA 1972.

But I can't find a proof of that, can anyone of you help me?

Comment: How do you define "stably free"? By $P\oplus R^m\cong R^{\left(X\right)}$ for some (possibly infinite) set $X$ but finite $m$ ? Then see exercise 1.9 of http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook/Kbook.I.pdf .

Comment: (Note that Weibel considers only the case $\left|X\right|=\Aleph_0$, but the proof works for all cases. I am rather unhappy with the hint given in Weibel, however; it could be written up in a better way.)

Comment: Ah, this is better: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/stablyfree.pdf Thm. A.1.

Comment: thanks, however the definition I know is: a stably free module is a finitely generated module $P$ such that there exist finitely generated free modules $F$ and $F^\prime$ such that $P\oplus F\cong F^\prime$

Comment: With this definition all stably free modules are finitely generated.

Comment: yeah, in the question I should have said, if a not finitely generated module $M$ has two free modules $F$ and $F^\prime$ such that $F\oplus M\cong F^\prime$ then $M$ is free. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: But then the Eilenberg swindle trick makes all projective modules
stably free: $P\bigoplus Q=F^\alpha$ and then 
$$
F^{\aleph_0\alpha}=(P\bigoplus Q)\bigoplus(P\bigoplus Q)\bigoplus\cdots=
$$
$$
P\bigoplus(P\bigoplus Q)\bigoplus(P\bigoplus Q)\bigoplus\cdots=
P\bigoplus F^{\aleph_0\alpha} 
$$

Comment: Add in my previous comment $F$ finitely generated :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the proof contained in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/stablyfree.pdf (link given by darij grinberg) it's the best proof. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Let $P\oplus R^k$ be free.  By induction it's enough to take $k=1$, so the assertion comes down to saying that an infinitely long unimodular row can be completed to an infinite invertible matrix.  But an infinitely long unimodular row contains (after rearrangement) a finitely long unimodular sub-row.  So it suffices to show that any unimodular row with a non-trivial initial unimodular sub-row can be completed.

Write the row as (s,x,t) where s is is unimodular and x has length 1.  Let p be a column such that s.p = 1.  Consider the matrix

$$\matrix{s&x&t\cr I&p&0\cr 0&0&I\cr}$$

where the $I$'s and $0$'s are identity and 0 matrices of approrpiate sizes.  This is easily seen to be invertible.

Comment: (Of course these "rows" need not be countable.)

Comment: "so the assertion comes down to saying that an infinitely long unimodular row can be completed to an infinite invertible matrix." I don't understand this very first step. Can you explain it?

Comment: Martin:  We are given an isomorphism $R^M\rightarrow R\oplus P$ (with $M$ possibly infinite).  The restriction $R^M\rightarrow R$ is represented by a unimodular row.  If $P$ is free, then the isomporphism itself is represented by an invertible matrix with that row as its first row.

Is there a problem with this that I'm failing to see?  

Comment: @StevenLandsburg The first minor is a square, finite matrix, so that will be invertible as well. This would seem to make the proof work also for the finite case. In fact, if I did not make any mistake in my computation, that minor (hence the whole matrix) will be invertible iff $x- 1$ is a unit, which may or may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The proper definition of 'stably free' is as follows: let $\Lambda$ be a ring. Then a $\Lambda$-module $S$ is stably free when $S\oplus\Lambda^n$ is a free module of unspecified rank, finite or infinite, where $n$ is an integer. The reason that $n$ must be finite is to avoid Eilenberg's trick which shows that $P\oplus \Lambda^\infty \cong \Lambda^\infty$ for any countably generated projective module $P$. Here $\Lambda^\infty$ denotes the direct limit ${\lim}_{\to}\Lambda^n$ where $\Lambda^n\subset\Lambda^n\oplus\Lambda\cong\Lambda^{n+1}$ under the inclusion $x\mapsto (x,0)$.

Gabel's theorem actually holds for non-commutative rings also. There is a proof in T.Y. Lam, Serre's conjecture. Although Gabel's theorem does not hold for projective modules,  a theorem of Kaplansky [Projective modules, Ann. of math, 68:2 (1958) 372 - 377]  says that every projective module is a direct sum of countably generated projective modules, and so even infinitely generated projectives cannot be 'too bad'.

Comment: I guess Eilenburg is a typo.

Comment: Ah yes. Not strictly a typo; I'm just a terrible speller.  

Comment: The Eilenberg Swindle shows that for any projective module $P$, there is a free module $F$ with $P \oplus F \cong F$.